# Data and image transformation in Flux.jl

Tags: julia, flux.jl

Coming from the PyTorch Vision ecosystem where there is a robust API for transformations, I am trying to find the analog in the Flux.jl ecosystem. I saw in the Flux docs that it mentions [Augmenter.jl](https://evizero.github.io/Augmentor.jl/), is this the defacto package to do image transformations or is there a built in Flux way of doing it?